# Managed Fusion URL Rewriter 500 error when compiled to .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-rewriting

I'm trying to take a .net 2.0 app into the .net 4.0 world.  We are leaving the webforms as is and adding new functionality in MVC2.

While we could redo all of our managed fusion rewrites as mvc routes, so for the moment, I'd rather just add the new routes to MF and have it handle url rewriting duties for both webforms and controllers.

I got it working on .net 3.5, but when the web app is compiled to 4.0 and the app pool set to 4.0, any url throws a 500 error.  Nothing interesting appears in the event logs either.

I tried downloading the source and compiling MF to 4.0, but no dice.  Any suggestions on getting this to work?  Is there a way to get MF to output detailed errors that can help identify the problem?

B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually the developer of Managed Fusion Url Rewriter.  The Url Rewriter doesn't need to be compiled to 4.0  to work under 4.0.  You can leave it compiling under 2.0 and it will still work with the integrated pipeline on IIS and .NET 4.0.  You can download the latest source from here:

http://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-rewriter/tree/master/Source/

Also I created a project that allows you to define your MVC routes in your rewriter config log here:

http://github.com/managedfusion/managedfusion-rewriter-contrib/tree/master/Source/

And can read more about the project here:

http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/editable-mvc-routes-apache-style/

As for the 500 errors, I am probably going to need a little more information, can you please update your post to include maybe a log from the rewriter enabled by adding the following to the top of your rewriter:

```
RewriteLog "log.txt"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

This should help us better diagnose where the 500 error is coming from.  But given all of have written above, I have concerns that you may not understand the difference between routes and rewriting, which many developers don't because they are sort of similar in what they accomplish.  Which is why I wrote the following post:

http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/difference-between-routing-rewriting/

If you want to work off line from StackOverflow back on the forum I would be happy to help you.

http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=228348